# How to add additional control key?

Tags: xkb, xmodmap

I am using xkb to add an additional control key as follows:

```
   key <HENK> { [  Control_R                 ] };
```

However, it does not work.

I even tried xmodmap without success:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Henkan_Mode = Control_R"
```

I had no problems adding additional shift key using similar codes as above. So I don't understand why the same code does not work with the control key.

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick:

```
modifier_map Control {  <HENK>  };
```

Comment: Did you put this directly a file in /usr/share/X11/xkb or via a command?

Comment: That's directly onto a file in: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/